# Sorting table records in django

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7

I am using a search field in django that searches hotel names from the hotel table based on the hotel names.
For searching I am using django's  function `__search`

```
data=request.POST.get("data") 
data=models.hotels.objects.filter(name__search=name)
```

By default it searches in BOOLEAN MODE

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE MATCH(name)AGAINST('data' IN BOOLEAN MODE );
```

But results comming are not arranged according to bests match 
is there any method to change the search function to make query like this :

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE MATCH(name)AGAINST('data');
```

that remove the boolean sorting mode with the best match on top ?

Comment: Several advices on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529703/django-full-text-search-order-by-relevance

Comment: or try raw sql queries: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

Answer (score 1):

Using "search" is easy in Django. Here I am trying to search names from a report generated.

```
from django.db.models import Q

def report(request):
    data = Subscribers.objects.all()
    template = 'report.html'
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        data = data.filter(
            Q(billNumber__icontains=query) |
            Q(name__icontains=query) |
            Q(area__icontains=query) |
            Q(phoneNumber__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()
    return render(request, template, {'entries': data})
```

In the html page where you want to implement the search add the following code:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Subscribers.." value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
</form>
```